# Displaying an error, but doesn't specify where

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working with a sample I found online. A week ago I loaded it on my phone and it worked fine.

Today I tried to load it again and it shows error.

[image: The project]

The actual error changes and even disapears at times.
I've tried reimporting it and it didn't help.

I read online that it might be a problem with the jar files. Unfortunately, when I right click them, some of them can't be deleted. I tried deleting the one gcm that could be deleted and it gave even more errors.

Any ideas?

If more screens/info is needed to know what the problem is, please let me know...

Thanks

EDIT:

I tried everything suggested without success.

Here is what it displays now:

[image: Console]

What doesn't make sense is that the exact same code worked a week ago... I haven't changed anything

Comment: just check your resource file layouts properly..

Comment: any error show in console ?

Comment: Well, it is a different error every time I import it. At first it was something with TelephonyManager, then BufferOverflowException, and last time it was "Unable to resolve target: Google API..."

Comment: Try a clean build or if that doesn't work, restart eclipse

Comment: do you have any hidden files (starting with a ".") in the libs directory?

Comment: I tried it. No, no hidden files starting with dot.
I added a screenshot of the error it displays now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

Go to Project » Properties » Java Build Path » Libraries and remove all except the "Android X.Y". click OK. Go to Project » Clean » Clean projects selected below » select your project and click OK. That should work.